# CodeIgniter, rewrite urls, call custom controller

Tags: codeigniter

I have completed CMS.
This CMS have many controllers: news, content, articles, etc.
Also have modules like "modules/shop/controllers/cart.php",  "modules/shop/controllers/items.php".

ATM URLs are:

- /shop/some-category/
- /shop/nokia/n73.html
- /content/about-company.html
- /articles/phones/full/1.html

Now I need urls like:
 - /nokia.html
 - /my/super/article-about-phones.html

So, I need custom URLs for any controlles (shop, news, content, etc).
As I know, I can't execute controller from controller.

How I can solve a problem?
I have no idea how to rewrite Router core class. Any ideas?
For me I have 1 way - rewrite architecture of full product but I have no time :(
Thnx alot.

P.S. ATR routes.php is:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$lang_prefix = '(([a-z]{2}/)?)';

$route[$lang_prefix.'ajax/shop/(.*)'] = "shop/ajax/$3";

$route['cron/(.*)'] = "cron/$1";

$route[$lang_prefix.'content/(.*)'] = "content/index";
$route[$lang_prefix.'faq/ask/(.*)'] = "faq/ask";
$route[$lang_prefix.'faq/(.*)'] = "faq/index";

$route[$lang_prefix.'sitemap'] = "sitemap/index";
$route[$lang_prefix.'contact'] = "contacts/index";

$route[$lang_prefix.'news/(.*?)/full/[0-9]+'] = "news/full";
$route[$lang_prefix.'news/(.*)'] = "news/index";



$route[$lang_prefix.'compare/[0-9]+[0-9\/]+'] = "shop/compare";
$route[$lang_prefix.'cart/(.*?)'] = "shop/cart/$3";
$route[$lang_prefix.'cart'] = "shop/cart";

$route[$lang_prefix.'order'] = "shop/order";
$route[$lang_prefix.'order/check'] = "shop/order";
$route[$lang_prefix.'order/successful/[A-z_\-0-9]+'] = "shop/order/successful";

$route[$lang_prefix.'search/(name|price|rating)/(asc|desc)(.*)'] = "shop/search";

$route[$lang_prefix.'shop/(.*)/(name|price|rating)/(asc|desc)(.*?)'] = "shop/items/index";
$route[$lang_prefix.'shop/(.*?)/(.*?)/add-comment'] = "shop/items/add_comment";
$route[$lang_prefix.'shop/(.*?)/(.*?)'] = "shop/items/details";
$route[$lang_prefix.'shop/(.*)'] = "shop/items/index";



$route[$lang_prefix.'feedback'] = "feedback/index";
$route[$lang_prefix.'callback'] = "feedback/index";

$route[$lang_prefix.'article/(.*?)/full/(.*)'] = "articles/full";
$route[$lang_prefix.'article/(.*)'] = "articles/index";

$route[$lang_prefix.'gallery/(.*?)/full/(.*)'] = "gallery/full";
$route[$lang_prefix.'gallery/(.*)'] = "gallery/index";


$route[$lang_prefix.'admin/ajax/(.*)'] = "admin/ajax/$3";
$route[$lang_prefix.'admin'] = "admin/main/index";


$route[$lang_prefix.'admin/login'] = "admin/auth/login";
$route[$lang_prefix.'admin/logout'] = "admin/auth/logout";

$route[$lang_prefix.'admin/(.*)'] = "admin/$3";

$route['default_controller'] = "shop/showcase";
```

Comment: you need your url to contain the file extension `.html` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mod_rewrite to direct all requests to a .html file to go to a special static content controller. So:

```
my/super/article-about-phones.html
```

would redirect to:

```
/content/static/article-about-phones/
```

This might look something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule  ^(.+)/([^/]+)\.html$ /content/static/$1/ [NC,L]
```